# PineScript - Strategy.entry order amount

Tags: pine-script, algorithmic-trading, trading, pine-script-v4

This is my strategy heading script:

```
strategy(title="NEWSTRAT",shorttitle="NS" , initial_capital=1000, currency=currency.USD, pyramiding = 5, overlay=true)
```

I created about 5 different "strategy.entry" and "strategy.close". According to the heading I want to spend 1000$, but I want each entry to use an equal amount (in this case 200$).

My questions:

1- Do I have to specify it in "strategy.entry" as a parameter, or I should add it to the strategy heading? (In order to equality distribute the order amount from the "initial_capital" amount "strategy.entry"s)

2- I set pyramiding to 5. Sometimes I see that the strategy takes a long from the same "strategy.entry", is there a way to block new entries if the initial "strategy.entry is still not closed. (example: "strategy.entry("LongA")"  detects an entry for long. Due to volatility, another strategy recognizes another similar entry as "strategy.entry("LongA")" and enters long even though the initial "strategy.entry("LongA")" is still open. so basically I want it not to enter a "strategy.entry("LongA")" long (same entry) if there is another open "strategy.entry("LongA")".)

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

This is possibly too late now, but hopefully this helps someone fi they come across this post like I did.

@vaibhav maathur was right that you should use the default_qty_type = strategy.cash and then use default_qty_value = (initial capital divided by number of pyramids) to evenly distribute your capital across your trades.

In regards to the second part of your question "How do I stop duplicate entries", there are a couple of ways to do this.

**1. Using strategy.opentrades.entry_id function(trade_num)**

This function returns the id of an open trade.  If your strategy is doing a lot of trades, then you may not know the trade_num for your order.  So instead we can simply loop through all open trades to check if any open trade has a matching id. If it already exists then don't open a new trade.

e.g.

```
for x=0 to strategy.opentrades -1 by 1
    if strategy.opentrades.entry_id(x) == "Long A"
        buyCondition := false

if buyCondition
    strategy.entry("Long A",strategy.long)
```

The problem with this method is it will only find open trades and wont find any limit/stop orders that have been placed but have not yet filled.  If there is a pending order with the same id, then the new order will modify it.

**2. Create your own array to track your orders**

Every time you place an order, just add that order's id into an array. Every time you close that trade, remove it from the array.  You can then use the same method of looping through your array to check if an order with that id already exists.

This method will catch pending orders which have not yet been filled.

e.g.

```
var array_OpenOrders = array.new_string(na)

if buyCondition
    for x=0 to array.size(array_OpenOrders) -1 by 1
        if array.get(array_OpenOrders, x) == "Long A"
            buyCondition := false

if buyCondition
    strategy.entry("Long A", strategy.long)
    array.push(array_OpenOrders, "Long A")

if sellCondition
    strategy.exit("Sell Long A", "Long A", Limit = close)
    for x=0 to array.size(array_OpenOrders)
        if array.get(array_OpenOrder,x) == "Long A"
            array.remove(array_OpenOrders,x)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you might want to use strategy.cash as the default_qty_type in the Strategy's declaration statement:
strategy("strategy.cash", overlay = true, default_qty_value = 1000, default_qty_type = strategy.cash, initial_capital = 1000000)

You can search for strategy.cash in the Pine Script language reference manual to find more details.

Similarly, strategy.fixed can help buy exactly the same number of shares or contracts on each entry.

The catch is that the Strategy.entry or Strategy.order statement must not specify the qty as a parameter, in order for the exact cash or exact fixed number of shares/contracts to be used for the order.